# Inventory: Items don't show up & are picked up twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inventory

I'm very new to Unity, so I hope someone can help me.
I'm trying to code an inventory for my game. I've worked with this tutorial on YT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoD_F1fSFFg&list=PL9JG3IlUvOUH_7EHF-dTCanunbDcq-iBQ&index=19&ab_channel=SoloGameDev
I made a few changes, like opening and closing the inventory window with I key instead of a button & picking up objects with E key instead of having to click on them.

Now two problems occured for me:

1. The picked up items are not displayed in the inventory window
2. The items are picked up twice

I've searched the internet for a solution but I didn't manage to make my code work as I'm not sure where I have to change it. I guess I have to change something in InventoryManager/InventoryOpener? I hope someone can help me because I really want to understand this. Thank you very much :)

Here's all my code related to the inventory:
**Item.cs:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName ="New Item", menuName ="Item/Create New Item")]

public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
    public int id;
    public string itemName;
    public Sprite icon;
}
```

**ItemController.cs:**

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class ItemController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Item Item;
    }
```

**ItemPickup.cs:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemPickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Item Item;
    public GameObject PickupText;

    void Start()
    {
        PickupText.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Pickup()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            InventoryManager.Instance.Add(Item);
            Destroy(gameObject);
            PickupText.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log(Item.itemName + " added to inventory");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        PickupText.SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log("Player is in pickup range");
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        Pickup();
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        PickupText.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("Player is outside pickup range");
    }

}
```

**InventoryOpener.cs:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InventoryOpener : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject inventory;
    private bool isOpen;

    void Start()
    {
        isOpen = !isOpen;
    }
   
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            if(isOpen == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("Inventory closed");
                inventory.SetActive(false);
                isOpen = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Inventory opened");
                inventory.SetActive(true);
                isOpen = true;
            }
        
           
        }   
    }
}
```

**InventoryManager.cs:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InventoryManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static InventoryManager Instance;
    public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();

    public Transform ItemContent;
    public GameObject InventoryItem;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    public void Add(Item item)
    {
        Items.Add(item);
        Debug.Log("An item was added to the item list");
    }

    public void Remove(Item item)
    {
        Items.Remove(item);
    }

    public void ListItems()
    {
        foreach (Transform item in ItemContent)
        {
            Destroy(item.gameObject);
        }

        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(InventoryItem, ItemContent);
            var itemName = obj.transform.Find("ItemName").GetComponent<Text>();
            var itemIcon = obj.transform.Find("ItemIcon").GetComponent<Image>();

            itemName.text = item.itemName;
            itemIcon.sprite = item.icon;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, quickly looking through the video you linked, at 11:43 they start making a method in the **InventoryManager.cs** called `SetInventoryItems()` and they then call it at the end of `ListItems()` method. You don't have this method defined. This should solve the issue of items not being displayed in the inventory

About the items being picked up twice, are you sure that they are added to the `Items` list twice? Or are the logs just being displayed twice?

Comment: Oh maybe I missed that part. I will try that! Thx.
About picking up twice: In the ItemManager I can see they are picked up twice because each item shows up in the list twice.

Comment: That is strange that the items are added twice. DId you get the items to show in the inventory?